# Exception: The merge filter only works with arrays or hashes in "HerzultForumBundle:Topic:new.html.twig"

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization

I'm improving my web application by adding more languages. I've done it following this tutorial: https://coderwall.com/p/eiqd_g

Everything seemed to work fine, but now I've figured out that when trying to create a new post on the forum ([HerzultForumBundle](https://github.com/Herzult/HerzultForumBundle)), I get the above exception.

I can see in the debugger:

*in kernel.root_dir/cache/dev/classes.php at line 8422*

```
function twig_array_merge($arr1, $arr2)
{
    if (!is_array($arr1) || !is_array($arr2)) {
        throw new Twig_Error_Runtime('The merge filter only works with arrays or hashes.');
    }
    return array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
}
```

*at **twig_array_merge (null, array('_locale' => 'en'))***
 *in kernel.root_dir/cache/dev/twig/c7/1/9188032d83474dae4ab5fad0cdaf278f4614c031cf7a5531428c5812bd57.php at line 200*

```
            echo ">
            \t        <a href=\"";
            // line 81
            echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, $this->env->getExtension('routing')->getPath($this->getAttribute($this->getAttribute((isset($context["app"]) ? $context["app"] : $this->getContext($context, "app")), "request"), "get", array(0 => "_route"), "method"), twig_array_merge($this->getAttribute($this->getAttribute((isset($context["app"]) ? $context["app"] : $this->getContext($context, "app")), "request"), "get", array(0 => "_route_params"), "method"), array("_locale" => (isset($context["locale"]) ? $context["locale"] : $this->getContext($context, "locale"))))), "html", null, true);
            echo "\">";
            echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, (isset($context["locale"]) ? $context["locale"] : $this->getContext($context, "locale")), "html", null, true);
            echo "</a>
```

So it seems like the `twig_array_merge()` function is getting a null value as first parameter. And the `HerzultForumBundle:Topic:new.html.twig` template seems to be the cause.
The `HerzultForumBundle:Topic:new.html.twig` template holds the below code:

```
{% extends 'HerzultForumBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}New Reply{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="forum  post_new">
<ul class="crumbs">
    <li><a href="{{ path('herzult_forum_index') }} ">Forum</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ forum_urlForCategory(topic.category) }}">{{ topic.category.name }}</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ forum_urlForTopic(topic) }}">{{ topic.subject }}</a></li>
    <li>New Reply</li>
</ul>
<div class="main">
    <h2>New Reply</h2>
    <form action="{{ url('herzult_forum_topic_post_create', { 'slug': topic.slug, 'categorySlug' : topic.category.slug }) }}" method="post">
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        <div>
            <button type="submit" name="reply">Add post</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="side">
    <p><a href="{{ forum_urlForTopic(topic) }}">Back to the topic</a></p>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

My guess is that the exception comes from this line:

`<form action="{{ url('herzult_forum_topic_post_create', { 'slug': topic.slug, 'categorySlug' : topic.category.slug }) }}" method="post">`

But don't know how to solve it. Any idea? The forum was working perfectly before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, here was my problem, in the base template:

```
<ul id="languages">{% for locale in ['en', 'fr', 'es', 'de'] %}
    <li {% if locale == app.request.locale %}class="active"{% endif %}>
        <a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale' : locale})) }}">{{ locale }}</a>
    </li>
        {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

So figured that `app.request.get('_route_params')` was null. I tried:

```
<ul id="languages">{% for locale in ['en', 'fr', 'es', 'de'] %}
    <li {% if locale == app.request.locale %}class="active"{% endif %}>
        {% if app.request.get('_route_params') %} <a href="{{ path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale' : locale})) }}">{{ locale }}</a>{% endif %}
    </li>
        {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

And yes! It works. I won't have translations on the forum but never mind, I think it's pretty understandable in english.

Comment: Upvoted because I really liked your for loop approach :)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar bug "The merge filter only works with arrays or hashes in ..." in the template. whatever line it was, whatever change i did the line of the error moved but the message remained the same.. 
It appeared after I added i18n compatibility to my site only on the page where there was a form.

the reason was me using a ->forward() to another template depending on the presence of error or not.

So this error is indeed linked to routing problem.

I ended up rendering the template instead of forwarding to another page.